# Python 3.5.2 Calculator issue

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

This is what my calculator looks like at the moment. Im doing this for school python revision. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnEHn.jpg

I want when the person enter 2 numbers it answers it like this 5+5=10

Comment: Paste your code into the question (don't forget to format it). Also, your code won't run as desired because all `or` conditions are wrong.

Comment: my code does run its just in that imgur i was trying to do it

Comment: You shouldn't `calculation == "some" or "other"`. You should `calculation == "some" or calculation == "other"`

Comment: or even `calculation in ["some", "other"]`

Comment: yer i fixed that now

Comment: but how will i display for example 5+5=10

Answer (score 0):

You should change from

```
print(number1+number2)
```

to

```
print("%d + %d = %d" % (number1, number2, number1+number2))
```

and so on for each operation.